# Proving isomorphism of vector fields on a smooth manifold with derivations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is problem 19.11 from Loring Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds [1 ed.].

Vector fields as derivations of $C^\infty$ functions.

In Subsection 14.1 we showed that a $C^\infty$ vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$ gives rise to a derivation of $C^\infty(M)$.
We will now show that every derivation of $C^\infty (M)$ arises from one and only one vector field. To distinguish the vector filed from the derivation, we will temporarily denote the derivation arising from $X$ by $\phi(X)$. Thus, for any $f \in C^\infty(M)$,
$$(\phi(X)f)(p)=X_p f \; \text{for all } p \in M.$$

(a) Let $\mathscr{F} = C^\infty (M).$ Prove that $\phi: \mathfrak{X}(M) \to Der(C^\infty(M))$ is an $\mathscr{F}-$linear map.

(b) Show that $\phi$ is injective.

(c) If $D$ is a derivation of $C^\infty(M)$ and $p \in M$, define $D_p : C_p^\infty(M) \to C_p^\infty(M)$ by

$$D_p[f]=[D\tilde{f}]\in C_p^\infty(M),$$ where $[f]$ is the germ of $f$ at $p$ and $\tilde{f}$ is a global extension of $f$. Show that $D_p[f]$ is well-defined.

(d) Show that $D_p$ is a derivation of $C_p^\infty(M)$.

(e) Prove that $\phi : \mathfrak{X} \to Der(C^\infty(M))$ is an isomorphism of $\mathscr{F}-$modules.

I proved (a)-(d), however, I can't figure out how to show the isomorphism in (e). How can we prove surjectivity of the linear map $\phi$ using (c) and (d)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D\in Der(C^\infty(M))$. For any $p\in M$ and $f\in C_pM$ define $X_p(f)=D_p(f)(p)$.

Then check:

$\bullet$ $X_p:C_pM\to \mathbb R$ , $f\mapsto X_p(f)$ is a tangent vector at $p$

$\bullet$ $X:M\to TM$, $p\mapsto X_p$ is a smooth vectorfield (Hint: Proposition 14.3)

$\bullet$ $\phi(X)=D$

Comment: Given a derivation $D$, how do we guarantee that for $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $D(f) \in C^\infty(M)$, $D(f)$ evaluated at $p \in M$ is equal to $D_p[f]$ evaluated at $p$? It seems like we need this to show that $\phi(X)=D$.

Comment: $D_p[f]$ is by definition $ [D\tilde f]$ for any globally defined local extension of $f$. Since here $f$ is allready globally defined $D_p[f]=[D(f)]$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose we may just consider how to define a derivation without applying (c) and (d). A derivation denotes a map $f\mapsto Xf$ while it satisfies some other properties. Hence we can illuminate $\phi$ as
$$\begin{aligned}
\phi:\mathfrak{X}(M)&\longrightarrow\mathrm{Der}(C^\infty(M)), \\
X&\longmapsto (f\mapsto Xf).
\end{aligned}$$
Then for any $D=(f\mapsto Xf)\in\mathrm{Der}(C^\infty(M))$, we can find a $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that $\phi(X)=D$. Thus $\phi$ is surjective.